# Google analytics : Can I use custom dimension name instead of index while showing data on Report On my Site

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

i am using Google Analytics Api to show data. But my Custom Dimension Data will Shows Header As

[image]

But i want to see table header as SchoolName or something else instead of Custom Dimension 3.

```
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({ 'serverAuth': { 'access_token': token } });

                var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
                    query: {
                        'ids': 'ga:111090746',
                        metrics: 'ga:totalEvents',
                        dimensions: dimension,
                        'start-date': '30daysAgo',
                        'end-date': 'yesterday',
                        'filters': 'ga:eventAction==' + filter,
                        'max-results': maxSize,
                        output: 'dataTable',
                        'totalResults': 'integer',
                    },
                    chart: {
                        container: 'declare-career-container',
                        type: 'TABLE',
                        options: {
                            showRowNumber: true,
                            page: 'enable',
                            pageSize: '10',
                            sortColumn: 0,
                            sortAscending: false,
                            'width': 650,
                            'height': 400,
                            'headerRow': 'header',
                        }
                    }

                });
                dataChart.on('success', function (response) {
                    var lbl = document.getElementById('totalCount');
                    lbl.textContent = response.response.totalResults;
                });
                dataChart.execute();
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? What programming language/s are you using or want to use? Can you show your code and why it is not working?

Comment: i am using javascript

Comment: I don't think you can.   You are using the embedded API its just going to display the default column name returned by the API.  If you want the name of the custom dimension you have to go though the management api.   For that your going to have to code the chart yourself a not using the embed api. https://developers.google.com/chart/?hl=en

Comment: thanks DalmTo
"For that your going to have to code the chart yourself a not using the embed api." if i am using this again facing one issue, issue is i have a drop down on my page for first time it works fine but if i change drop down value to get another report it shows  me "You called the draw() method with the wrong type of data rather than a DataTable or DataView"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the user defined column in your google analytics account

1. Sign in to your Google Analytics account.
2. Select the Customization tab, at the top of any page in Analytics.
3. Select Custom Reports in the left navigation.
4. Your reports will be listed in the left navigation under Custom Reports.
5. If no custom reports have been created, you will only see an entry for Overview under Custom Reports.

reference: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033013